# How can I get the installed ALSA version?

Tags: alsa, versions

How can I see what ALSA version is installed on my machine?

I tried:

```
$ alsa --version
Usage: /sbin/alsa {unload|reload|force-unload|force-reload|suspend|resume}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To find out the version of alsa you are using, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
cat /proc/asound/version
```

Answer (score 5):

The version of the kernel drivers is shown in `/proc/asound/version`, but this depends only on your kernel version (and the latest version shows nothing but the kernel version number).

To get the version number of the user-space tools, execute `aplay --version`.

Comment: `aplay` is part of the `alsa-utils` package. But the other user-space packages are typically updated in parallel.