# Alsa for Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS

Tags: alsa

How can find what version of Alsa is installed and update it to the latest version
Google search shows very very old suggestions which do not work 
Alsa official website does not provide any information suitable for end users who are new to this, just for programmers and developers

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackExchange AskUbuntu!

Get the installed version of Alsa with `cat /proc/asound/version`
(https://askubuntu.com/a/394852/359408)

Update your system with

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

(updates all packages, including ALSA). Not that the version Ubuntu installs might not be the most recent release of ALSA, but the most recently tested version for your version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response